# Generating a not-the-same-as-last-time random number

Tags: java, random, comparative-review

I have to generate random number which differs from the number generated last time.

Which of these two variants is better? Or maybe you can suggest better implementation.

```
int generateRandom() {
    int randomNumber;
    do {
        randomNumber = random.nextInt(UPPER_BOUND);
    } while (randomNumber == lastRandomNumber);
    lastRandomNumber = randomNumber;
    return randomNumber;
}
```

vs

```
int generateRandom() {
    while (true) {
        int randomNumber = random.nextInt(UPPER_BOUND);
        if (randomNumber != lastRandomNumber) {
            lastRandomNumber = randomNumber;
            return randomNumber;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is verified to work correctly?

Comment: @Pimgd yes. Why do you ask? What's wrong with this code snippet?

Comment: It's vital for my answer.

Comment: @LeonidSemyonov Your second snippet needs `randomNumber` to be declared somewhere. Obviously, it should be declared in the method itself.

Comment: @maaartinus I corrected the snippet.

Comment: Same goes for `lastRandomNumber` in the first snippet :-)

Comment: @CompuChip `lastRandomNumber` is a field

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Neither option is great. Looking at the second option first (because it is the worst, in my opinion):

> ```
> int generateRandom() {
>     while (true) {
>         int randomNumber = random.nextInt(UPPER_BOUND);
>         if (randomNumber != lastRandomNumber) {
>             lastRandomNumber = randomNumber;
>             return randomNumber;
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

This contains a seemingly infinite loop. `while(true)` is often an indication that there's a better way to do things (not necessarily always, but in this case, yes). The reason it is a problem here is because it gives the impression that the loop repeats often, when, in fact, it seldom repeats ever.

The first block is better:

> ```
> int generateRandom() {
>     int randomNumber;
>     do {
>         randomNumber = random.nextInt(UPPER_BOUND);
>     } while (randomNumber == lastRandomNumber);
>     lastRandomNumber = randomNumber;
>     return randomNumber;
> }
> ```

This is better because the loop-terminating condition is much cleaner, more visible. The logic-path through the method is traditional. Still, it's not great. I dislike the need to declare the `randomNumber` variable as a separate declaration.

The 'while loop' solution would be more readable (even though it duplicates the `nextInt()` call), as:

```
int generateRandom() {
    int randomNumber = random.nextInt(UPPER_BOUND);
    while (randomNumber == lastRandomNumber) {
        randomNumber = random.nextInt(UPPER_BOUND);
    }
    lastRandomNumber = randomNumber;
    return randomNumber;
}
```

Even with the code duplication, it makes it clear that the normal case is handled, and then the while loop is a recovery process.

[@Pimgd suggested](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/66625/31503) sending the `lastRandomNumber` in as a parameter, and [@maartinus suggested](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/66624/31503) a single if-block condition rather than a while loop solution. In principle these are both good ideas. There *is* a way to make it completely reentrant, and also a way to remove the while-loop and the id-conditionals. My solution would be:

```
int generateRandom(int lastRandomNumber) {

    // add-and-wrap another random number to produce a guaranteed
    // different result.
    // note the one-less-than UPPER_BOUND input
    int rotate = 1 + random.nextInt(UPPER_BOUND - 1);
    // 'rotate' the last number
    return (lastRandomNumber + rotate) % UPPER_BOUND;

}
```

@mjolka pointed out that if UPPER_BOUND is large, it is possible for the values to overflow in the sum, and that the better solution would be:

```
return ((lastRandomNumber + rotate) & Integer.MAX_VALUE) % UPPER_BOUND;
```

Comment: Aaand he solved it. There you go, a one liner solution if you replace `rotate` with its value. I salute thee.

Comment: `body; while (condition) { body; }` defeats the whole point of the `do { body } while (condition);` language feature. I'd say that it's definitely worse than both of the originals.

Answer (score 4):

Neither? Both look fine. I'd just rename `randomNumber` to something else (e.g., `result`) as I found similarly names bad.

You surely know, that it never terminates for `UPPER_BOUND == 1`, but as this is a constant, there's no need for a check.

You could also optimize it to

```
int generateDifferentRandom() {
    // There's one less possible result, note the argument to random.
    int result = random.nextInt(UPPER_BOUND - 1);
    if (result == lastRandomNumber) {
        result = UPPER_BOUND - 1;
    }
    lastRandomNumber = result;
    return result;
}
```

but *I'm not suggesting it*. Your code looks cleaner, I just wanted to show an alternative.

---

Concerning thread-safety mentioned by Pimgd, it's surely something you should keep in mind. Passing `lastRandomNumber` as an argument solves it nicely, but often objects do need their own state. And most of them don't need to be thread-safe as they don't get used from multiple threads. You could simply add `synchronized` or use `AtomicInteger#compareAndSet` to obtain thread-safety, but usually, you don't have to.

Comment: This solution will tend to return `UPPER_BOUND - 1` as a value more often than any other value, which makes the randomness wrong.

Comment: @rolfl I haven't tested it... but have you noticed the upper bound I'm passing to the random call? Because of it, `UPPER_BOUND-1` will be returned *only in case of collisions*. It can't be returned twice in a row as it can't be generated by `random.nextInt(UPPER_BOUND - 1)`. Note that I clearly said, I'm not recommending this. It's correct, but as we can see, pretty unclear. Btw., it's a common trick for returning constrained random numbers.

Comment: Ahh, I see where I went wrong, you should make it more clear that the `upperbound-1` is the input to the `nextInt`, as it is not immediately obvious that it is, and the consequences of that subtlety are significant.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say both of them could use an improvement:

You use a class member variable `lastRandomNumber`. This means your functions are no longer thread-safe. Consider passing it in as an argument...

Next, you can use a trick used for reading files: `while((line = nextLine()) != null)`. What that does is "set line to the next line, then check if line is not null."

In your case, this would be

```
while((randomNumber = random.nextInt(UPPER_BOUND)) != lastRandomNumber){}
```

Making the result

```
int generateRandom(int lastRandomNumber){
    int randomNumber;
    while((randomNumber = random.nextInt(UPPER_BOUND)) != lastRandomNumber){}
    return randomNumber;
}
```

There's a version without a loop too:

```
int generateRandom(int lastRandomNumber){
    int randomNumber = random.nextInt(UPPER_BOUND - 1) + 1;
    if(randomNumber == lastRandomNumber){
        randomNumber = 0;
    }
    return randomNumber;
}
```

... and as a last nitpick, I think you should rename the method to be `generateRandomThatIsNot(int lastRandomNumber)`.

Comment: I hate this trick... I'd call it obfuscation. It's a leftover from times, when compilers were dumb.

Comment: In languages that allow implicit casting, there's an even nastier trick: `value = random(bound-1)+1; return value*(value!=lastValue);`.